# Proper way to make toolbar transparent / blurry with system color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having trouble figuring out how to properly make my toolbar `UIToolbarAppearance` to be transparent and at the same time white, as can be seen here from the app Signal, it nicely shows how its blurred out when the list scroll behind it and when there is no list behind its white as the background.

[image]

In my case I am having issue to achieve same result. Its transparent and blurry but the ultra thin material is displaying the toolbar more as gray than white, and that's where I am stuck.

[image]

```
init() {
        // Customize UITabBar
        let toolbarBackground = UIToolbarAppearance()
        toolbarBackground.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterialDark)

        toolbarBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(dynamicProvider: { traitCollection in
            return traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8) : UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        })

        toolbarBackground.shadowColor = .clear
        UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolbarBackground
        UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolbarBackground
    }
```

I am assuming signal uses something else than `UltraThinMaterail`?

Comment: Do you have something underneath the toolbar? Ultra thin material wouldn't be grey otherwise?

Comment: Nothing else, this is the only material I used. I am able to change it to any color, but not transparent at the same time. But even trying `UltraThinMateria` on its own in an app seems to always have that different off color. So not really sure how they achieved it. Maybe its not the right approach to use `withAlphaComponent`?  @Sweeper

Comment: Wait why are you setting a black background color when you want it to be transparent?

Comment: thats for dark mode, to be black with semi transparency like a frosty glass effect. I don't want it to be fully transparent @Sweeper

Comment: seems like no matter how I adjust the `withAlphaComponent(0.8)` it will always have some off shade color @Sweeper